# Trouble parsing JsonObject - error 'String cannot be converted to JSONObject'

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Here is what I tried again but to no avail....

I switch String to double and change the values in the hashmap to accommodate doubles as well. Still getting the same error.....It difficult to find example of just pulling a jsonObject without an array

What the issue here ???

{
        "base": "EUR",
        "date": "2017-08-25",
        "rates": {
            "AUD": 1.4919,
            "BGN": 1.9558,
            "BRL": 3.7045,
            "CAD": 1.4769,
            "CHF": 1.139,
            "CNY": 7.8596,
            "CZK": 26.084,
            "DKK": 7.4391,
            "GBP": 0.92083,
            "HKD": 9.2372,
            "HRK": 7.414,
            "HUF": 304.68,
            "IDR": 15758.0,
            "ILS": 4.2453,
            "INR": 75.598,
            "JPY": 129.59,
            "KRW": 1327.0,
            "MXN": 20.844,
            "MYR": 5.0456,
            "NOK": 9.2278,
            "NZD": 1.6363,
            "PHP": 60.327,
            "PLN": 4.2598,
            "RON": 4.5983,
            "RUB": 69.831,
            "SEK": 9.5053,
            "SGD": 1.6055,
            "THB": 39.332,
            "TRY": 4.108,
            "USD": 1.1808,
            "ZAR": 15.549
        }
    }

---

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                JSONObject jsonObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates");


                double australia = jsonObj2.getDouble("AUD");
                double bulgarian = jsonObj2.getDouble("BDN");
                double brazil = jsonObj2.getDouble("BRL");
                double canadian = jsonObj2.getDouble("CAD");
                double swissfrank = jsonObj2.getDouble("CHF");
                double chinnese = jsonObj2.getDouble("CNY");
                double Czech = jsonObj2.getDouble("CZK");
                double Danish = jsonObj2.getDouble("DKK");
                double british = jsonObj2.getDouble("GBP");
                double hongkong = jsonObj2.getDouble("HKD");
                double croatian = jsonObj2.getDouble("HRK");
                double hungarian = jsonObj2.getDouble("HUF");
                double indonesian = jsonObj2.getDouble("IDR");
                double israeli = jsonObj2.getDouble("ILS");
                double indian = jsonObj2.getDouble("INR");
                double japan = jsonObj2.getDouble("JPY");
                double korean = jsonObj2.getDouble("KRW");
                double mexican = jsonObj2.getDouble("MXN");
                double malaysian = jsonObj2.getDouble("MYR");
                double norwegian = jsonObj2.getDouble("NOK");
                double newzealand = jsonObj2.getDouble("NZD");
                double philippino = jsonObj2.getDouble("PHP");
                double polish = jsonObj2.getDouble("PLN");
                double romanian = jsonObj2.getDouble("RON");
                double russian = jsonObj2.getDouble("RUB");
                double swedish = jsonObj2.getDouble("SEK");
                double singapore = jsonObj2.getDouble("SGD");
                double thai = jsonObj2.getDouble("THB");
                double turkish = jsonObj2.getDouble("TRY");
                double usa = jsonObj2.getDouble("USD");
                double southafrican = jsonObj2.getDouble("ZAR");

                // tmp hash map for single contact
                HashMap<String, Double> contact = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put("AUD", australia);
                contact.put("BDN", bulgarian);
                contact.put("BRL", brazil);
                contact.put("CAD", canadian);
                contact.put("CHF", swissfrank);
                contact.put("CNY", chinnese);
                contact.put("CZK", Czech);
                contact.put("DKK", Danish);
                contact.put("GBP", british);
                contact.put("HKD", hongkong);
                contact.put("HRK", croatian);
                contact.put("HUF", hungarian);
                contact.put("IDR", indonesian);
                contact.put("ILS", israeli);
                contact.put("INR", indian);
                contact.put("JPY", japan);
                contact.put("KRW", korean);
                contact.put("MXN", mexican);
                contact.put("MYR", malaysian);
                contact.put("NOK", norwegian);
                contact.put("NZD", newzealand);
                contact.put("PHP", philippino);
                contact.put("PLN", polish);
                contact.put("RON", romanian);
                contact.put("RUB", russian);
                contact.put("SEK", swedish);
                contact.put("SGD", singapore);
                contact.put("THB", thai);
                contact.put("TRY", turkish);
                contact.put("USA", usa);
                contact.put("ZAR", southafrican);


                // adding contact to contact list

                contactList.add(contact);
```

Comment: Your rates are not an ArrayType its Object type.

Comment: `getString("AUD").toString()` is redundant. You already are getting a string

Comment: try  Double australia = ratesObject.getDouble("AUD");

Answer (score 4):

> String cannot be converted to JSONObject

**Problem**

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
```

Why **[JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)**

```
"rates": {
        "AUD": 1.4919,
        "BGN": 1.9558,
```

**Sol** - Use **[Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)** with [**`JSONObject#keys`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys())

```
            Iterator<String>  iteratorObj = jsonObj2.keys();
            ArrayList<String> al_getAllKeys=new ArrayList<String>();
            while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
            {
                String key = iteratorObj.next();
                ..........
                System.out.println("Key_VALUE: " + key + "------>" + jsonObj2.getString(key));

            }
```

**FYI**

Why **`int australia`** ? . It should be **`double australia`** .

> double australia = ratesObject.getDouble("AUD");

Comment: @MarAvFe Agree . In that case i use `Iterator`

Comment: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                    JSONObject jsonObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates");


                    double australia = jsonObj2.getDouble("AUD");
                    double bulgarian = jsonObj2.getDouble("BDN");         still giving me the same error....

Answer (score 1):

You have no square brackets, so you don't need `JSONArray` related classes or methods at all.

Use `jsonObj2.getString("AUD")`

If you actually want numbers, use `getDouble("AUD")`

Comment: I tried without it aswell,  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONObject jsonObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates");



                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj2.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject ratesObject = jsonObj2.getJSONObject("rates");                 //still no luck :(

Comment: You don't need a loop at all, either

Comment: A `JSONObject` is basically the same as a HashMap.

Comment: jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

JSONObject jsonObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates");                                        I am getting still getting the same error

Comment: Why don't you just use `rateList.add(jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates"));` ? Do you really **need** the `HashMap`? Do you really need to parse the JSON in this function?

Comment: Note: `int australia = ratesObject.getString("AUD")` will not compile. You can't convert a String to an Int

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to Json

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(cursorUsers.getString("String");
```

When get String from JSONObject

```
String str=jsonObj.getString("parseObjectName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rates are in `double`, but you are calling `getString()` and store them in `int`!

Your `JsonArray array` is empty and you're looping through it!

`rates` is a jsonObject. No need to loop, just call it and access each rate by providing its key.

```
double aud = jsonObject2.getDouble("AUD");

double bnd = jsonObject2.getDouble("BND");
```

Comment: You cannot loop through a jsonObject, never. You need keep a separate list of keys so that you provide the key to jsonObject2.getDouble(key)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Google's Gson library with simple steps, try below code

```
String jsonString = "Your JSON string";

Gson gson = new Gson();

//Convert Json String to Json Object without a POJO class
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson (jsonString, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();

//Get rates object and convert it to hashmap (For easy access)
HashMap<String, String> ratesMap = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("rates").getAsString(), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType());
```